# Add the send button in facebook iframe like button

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-like, jsfiddle

I have this iframe and is displaying the facebook like button  but I can not add the send button. what should I  add to it? I was trying `send=true&amp;` but that soes not seems to work

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjJsk/45/)

```
 <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px">
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com/Eurekavi&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:20px;" allowTransparency="true">
  </iframe>
  <style>.fbook{position: absolute; font-color:#ddd; top:-1668px; font-size:10;}</style>
  <style>.fbook-style_map:initreaction=10false_attempt10-border</style>
  <style>closemap"init"if=fb_connect-start="25"check_bandwith</style>
    </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook developer documentation says: "Send Button (XFBML Only)". So you have to use XFBML for your like/send button:

include js-api once:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[your_app_id_here]";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

include namespace:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

insert like/send button (multiple times if you want):

```
<fb:like href="http://stackoverflow.com" send="true" layout="button_count" width="250" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

As per Facebook Documentation, You can NOT do this as of now!

Answer (score 0):

Now facebook replaced send with recommend

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com" data-layout="standard" data-action="recommend" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```